# DataTable DB Connection

Tags: c#

I have code to fetch a data table from a stored procedure. For some reason, it is never able to fetch the data from SQL Server.

```
var conSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBS-PB"].ConnectionString;

using(conDB = new SqlConnection(conSTR))
{
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_GetDeity";
            conDB.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            return dt;
}
```

During debug, `condb` contains data, but `dt` is blank. I have checked on SQL Server side, all is good. Please help. THANKS

Comment: Is ypur stored procedure is dynamic in nature or i can say are you making a dynamic query in stored procedure

Comment: Yep, I am making a simple select query

Comment: you need to change the code where you read `connectionStrings`

Comment: okie, So I now use:
var conSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBS-PB"].ConnectionString;
            using(conDB = new SqlConnection(conSTR))
But for some reason, Data Table never gets filled :S

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4):

you have created new connection, but never open it. ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection.

```
string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRKBS-PB"].ConnectionString;
using(conDB = new SqlConnection(constring))
using(cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetDeity", conDB))
{
    conDB.Open(); // open the connection
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: aint using supposed to take care of opening and closing. I am a beginner in C#

Comment: if OP does not open the connection he gets `ExecuteReader()` requires an Open Connection exception IMO.

Comment: `using` take care of disposing the object

Comment: @Rajiv `using` will take care of the disposing of the object (which will close connections gracefully in almost all cases), but not the opening or configuring of it. `using` is there to replace the need to have a `finally` block to close the connection when the code encounters an error

Comment: @Rajiv: the `SqlDataAdapter` class will take care of opening and closing the connection - but **only** that class. The `SqlDataReader` expects an open connection - it's **YOUR** responsibility to open it before calling `cmd.ExecuteReader()`